# Couldn't connect linux mysql server from other server

Tags: mysql, remote-access

I tried everything which I found on google but couldn't connect linux mysql server from other server, Server where Mysql is located is Linux OS and from where I want to connect that is ubuntu, What can I do?

I already grant all privileges to user, bind-ip-address, and comment localhost etc. Is there any sqlserver's internal configurations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long R&D, when nothing help me, I think about port number, and that was silly mistake, actually I check available port on AWS for that instance from I want to connect and found I forgot to open 3306 (default MySQL port). I just add this and everything became perfect.

Answer (score 2):

Did you check ssh connectivity between two servers? if it doesn't works configure sshd properly and if ssh connectivity works fine then,The Target server's internal firewall might be blocking remote mysql connections.